# How do I use .one() handler correctly?

Tags: jquery, insertafter

I want to insert a `div` element after a given element. How do I do it **ONCE** ?

This is what I have:

```
var i = 1;

$('<div id="plussign"></div>').one("insertAfter","#div" + i);
```

Comment: that's not what `one` is used for.

Comment: Why do you use loop if you want to insert once, though your code is incorrect also.

Comment: oh ... alright, I thought I could use it for any function.

Comment: well this is not my real code. I just wanted to exemplify my case with a "cut-down" version. My variables would give away too much information about my program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.one()` is the same thing as `.click()` except it works only *once* and then detaches itself.

You probably want to do this:

```
var $target = $('#div' + i);

if (!$target.next().hasClass('plussign')) {
  $('<div />', {'class': 'plussign'}).insertAfter($target);
}
```

Do note that I changed your `id` to a `class`. `id`s are unique and there cannot be two elements with the same `id` in the document. `class`, on the other hand, is not unique and can be used to group many elements together.

Comment: yes, but the purpose of my code is to only execute it ONCE. That is why I put it in bold letters. The for loop is really, really a dumb thing I inserted to exemplify my code (where there is no for loop). in reality, i is a normal variable.

Comment: Then what is the loop for? How can that run once if you run it `5` times? An explanation would be good.

Comment: well, as I said, in my code there is no for loop. I just wanted a variable to be in the code. And putting it into a for loop was just dumb, sorry. Look at my question, I edited it.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. Give me 30 seconds.

Comment: Doesn't `insertAfter` need a parameter?

Comment: Probably ;) Thanks for the catch.